# using create_date Automatic fields in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

I am follow odoo document and in chapter 9
I want to use Automatic field ( create_date) to compute value of another field
this is my model.

```
 _name = "estate.offer"
_description = "this is work as a offer offered to our real estate model"
_log_access = True
price = fields.Float()
status = fields.Selection(selection=[('accepted', 'Accepted'), ('refused', 'Refused')], copy=False)
partner_id = fields.Many2one("res.partner", string="Partner", required=True)
property_id = fields.Many2one("estate.model", 'offer_id', required=True)
validity = fields.Integer(compute="_inverse_date_deadline", inverse="_compute_date_deadline")
date_deadline = fields.Date(string="Date Deadline", compute="_compute_date_deadline",
                            inverse="_inverse_date_deadline")

api.depends('create_date', 'validity')
def _compute_date_deadline(self):
    for record in self:
        record.date_deadline = record.create_date + datetime.timedelta(days=record.validity)

# problem in this function
api.depends('create_date', 'date_deadline')
def _inverse_date_deadline(self):
    #print('f ddd {5} xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxzxxxxxxxxx')
    for record in self:
        record.validity = (record.date_deadline - record.create_date).days
```

in the odoo document they give this tip:

Tip: the create_date is only filled in when the record is created, therefore you will need a fallback to prevent crashing at time of creation.

Comment: Did you mean your function crashes because create_date not created or filled yet (while creation)?

Comment: yes that what happen exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odoo will raise the following error when it tries to compute the `validity` (`_inverse_date_deadline`):

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

The `date_deadline` field is of type `Date` and `create_date` is of type `DateTime`.

And the following error when it tries to compute or inverse the `date_deadline`:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'bool' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

This happens because `create_date` is not already set.

To fix those issues you can:

- Change the `date_deadline` field type or convert its value like folowing:

  ```
  fields.Datetime.to_datetime(record.date_deadline)
  ```
- Handle the empty `date_deadline` field value, if it is set, compute validity and if not, provide a default value (You [must assign](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/addons/orm.html#computed-fields) the computed value to the field).
- Handle the `create_date`, you can provide a default value when creating:

  ```
  record.create_date or fields.Datetime.now()
  ```

Comment: yes its work but fields not updated immediately. I mean if I enter validity,  date_deadline  should be changed instantaneously before save change in the form and vice versa.

Comment: If you change the validity and click outside the field, the value of date_deadline should update